# Selenium webdriver with Python - driver.title can't get title

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium. Could you explain why driver.title can't get the value? Below is a simple webdriver script. I was able to get the value on https://www.google.com, but not on https://twitter.com.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://twitter.com")

print(driver.title)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title for twitter is getting rendered a little slow, so you can use explicit wait here to wait for the element to get loaded first and then you can fetch the title.

You can do it like:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Log in']")))
print(driver.title)
```

**Note: You have to add the following imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It was helpful. Thank you very much. I was able to get the value. So I was trying to get the value before the title tag was rendered.

Answer (score -1):

Because google they have value within title tag
`<title>Google</title>` but not Twitter so you would not get anything if it is not there :)

Comment: Why can't I get the value even if the title tag is confirmed by the developer tools? For example https://twitter.com/kurusugawa_/media